# I cannot delete a folder from a driver (ubuntu 13.04)

Tags: command-line, drivers, 13.04, gui, rm

When i try to delete a folder from a drive its saying through UI

```
Error while deleting.
Could not remove the folder New_Movie
When i clicked show details , its showing
Could not remove the folder New_Movie
```

so i tried to delete that folder from command line , after i mount the driver when i try to delete that folder with the following command

```
rm -rf <Folder_Name>

rm: cannot remove ‘Folder_Name’: Directory not empty
```

additional information : even i tried to delete that in windows , its saying cannot delete the folder

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is going on with  your folder, but I'll throw some ideas you can try:

instead of `rm -rf New_Movie`, try `sudo rm -rv New_Movie` and see if it gives you a specific error.

Have you tried running fsck on that partition? Maybe the filesystem has errors.

You can reboot and force fsck to run as it reboots if you use `sudo shutdown -Fr` in a console.

try unmounting the folder before removing it:
`sudo umount New_Movie && rm -rf New_Movie`

hope it helps.